# How can I convert a Windows path to Unix?

Tags: bash

I want to create a program on Ubunut (WSL) that creates Folders and Text-documents. The user can type in a path, since Windows uses another path system we can’t just copy and paste. For convenience I want that the Windows path is automatically converted to a Unix path.
Via the:

```
read -r path;
```

i ready the path in.
How can I realize this, I tried multiple times. I also searched for answers in the internet but it never worked.
The converted path is the destination:

```
cd $path
```

this should be also possible.

I hope for helpful answers, because i am already desperate .

Comment: Possible:  https://superuser.com/questions/1113385/convert-windows-path-for-windows-ubuntu-bash

Comment: I know the version with wsl path but, for my program to work I need to save the path in a variable, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to accomplish what you are after by storing the Windows path as a Unix/Linux path variable in WSL:

Using the full path to the command of `wslpath` as a sub-command allows us to read in the "path" as a variable.  If you are not sure what the full path is simply use `which wslpath`.

The commands below are in sequence of read in the `path`. Then convert the `path` variable to a Unix path.  Then change to the `$path` folder.

```
read -r path;
path=$(/usr/bin/wslpath -a "$path")
cd "$path"
```

Example:

```
terrance@Terrance-Win10:~$ read -r path;
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\
terrance@Terrance-Win10:~$ path=$(/usr/bin/wslpath -a "$path")
terrance@Terrance-Win10:~$ cd "$path"
terrance@Terrance-Win10:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)$
```